# How to replace cartesian join with database join in pentaho

Tags: database, join, inner-join, pentaho-spoon, cartesian-product

can some one help me please?

I need to make range look up in pentaho PDI.

The first stream comes from "Table input" and contains column "IPNUM" (IP addresses in decadic format). The second stream (Country database) comes from "Table input 2".

[transformation overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au8Ej.png)

Stream 1
[Table input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON1VU.png)

Stream 2
[Table input 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPnee.png)

Cartesioan join
[cartesian join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feZgE.png)

Transformation look for country details based on IPNUM number which is found in number range bordered from "Start" to "Stop". There are two conditions as well. IPNUM >= Start and IPNUM <= Stop. These two condition is the rule for lookup node - determines the range for each country.

[cartesian join condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n2ce.png)

Can someone help how to replace cartesian join step with "database join step" with the same conditions? IPNUM >= Start and IPNUM <= Stop

[database join step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeWg4.png)

The problem is cartesion join is too slow and the database has over two millions lines. It is without the end.

Or some idea how to make this lookup faster?

Thank you for your help!